# How to compile examples in the book "The Linux Programming Interface" by Michael Kerrisk

Tags: c, linux

What should I do with the files `ename.c.inc`, `error_functions.c`, `error_functions.h`, `tlpi_hdr.h`?

I copied these files into /lib/ Directory. but I got the following Error when I tried to compile example listing 4.1, a simple copy function:

```
4.1_copy.c:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `usageErr'
4.1_copy.c:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `errExit'
4.1_copy.c:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `errExit'
4.1_copy.c:(.text+0x16f): undefined reference to `fatal'
4.1_copy.c:(.text+0x1b6): undefined reference to `errExit'
4.1_copy.c:(.text+0x1d7): undefined reference to `errExit'
4.1_copy.c:(.text+0x1f8): undefined reference to `errExit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What do I need to do to get this program to link?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

When you are compiling, try adding a path to the files that need to be included in copy.c, like this:

```
gcc -I ../lib -o copy copy.c
```

That -I argument, followed by the path, tells the compiler to search in that path for included files, hopefully including tlpi_hdr.h.

Alternatively, follow the instructions at the very bottom of [this page](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/fileio/copy.c.html) and run `make` from the directory where copy.c ends up.

Comment: Adding the include path doesn't help with undefined references at all. [Undefined references only occur at a much later stage of compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix). To fix those, add the relevant `libtlpi.a` file to the gcc command line.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I ran make on the book source code directory (after installing necessary dev packages libcap-dev and libacl1-dev). After successful compilation it generated a library file called libtlpi.a . I used that file as one of the files while compiling code. E.g.; $ gcc -o copy copy.c ../libtlpi.a